# touch equivalent for Hibernate entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, sql-update

I'd like to implement repository method `void touch(MyEntity myEntity)` which enforces SQL call of update of entity columns to their current values. (The reason behind is the `on update` trigger which needs to be invoked in some point of execution.) Ideal usecase is:

```
void serviceMethod(Long myEntityId) {
    MyEntity myEntity = myEntityRepository.findOne(myEntityId);
    ...
    myEntityRepository.touch(myEntity);
    ...
}
```

There are already similar questions on SO which don't work for me: [Force update in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370051/force-update-in-hibernate) (my entity is detached), [Implementing “touch” on JPA entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152481/implementing-touch-on-jpa-entity) (doing some harmless change works but is not general and has bad impact on code readability), [Hibernate Idempotent Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210947/hibernate-idempotent-update) (similar example).

I am aware of session interceptor method `findDirty` and also `CustomEntityDirtinessStrategy` both described in [this Vlad Mihalcea's article](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-customize-hibernate-dirty-checking-mechanism/). However, it seems to use `findDirty` I would have to override session interceptor, which is not possible from within repository method since the interceptor is final field assigned to session at session creation. And `CustomEntityDirtinessStrategy` comes from `SessionFactory` which is global. I rather need some one-shot solution to temporary consider one concrete entity of one concrete class dirty.

The so-far-best working solution is to set invalid (array of nulls) entity snapshot into persistence context, so that the subsequent logic in `flush()` evaluates entity as differing from snapshot and enforce update. This works:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void touch(final T entity) {
    SessionImpl session = (SessionImpl)em.getDelegate();
    session.update(entity);
    StatefulPersistenceContext pctx = (StatefulPersistenceContext) session.getPersistenceContext();
    Serializable id = session.getIdentifier(entity);
    EntityPersister persister = session.getEntityPersister(null, entity);
    EntityKey entityKey = session.generateEntityKey(id, persister);
    int length = persister.getPropertyNames().length;
    Field entitySnapshotsByKeyField = FieldUtils.getField(pctx.getClass(), "entitySnapshotsByKey", true);
    Map<EntityKey,Object> entitySnapshotsByKey = (Map<EntityKey,Object>)ReflectionUtils.getField(entitySnapshotsByKeyField, pctx);
    entitySnapshotsByKey.put(entityKey, new Object[length]);
    session.flush();
    em.refresh(entity);
}
```

The advice in [Force update in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370051/force-update-in-hibernate) didn't work for me because `session.evict(entity)` clears `entitySnapshotsByKey` entry at all, which causes subsequent `org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener#getDatabaseSnapshot` loads fresh entity from db. The question is 9 years old and I'm not sure if it's applicable to current version of Hibernate (mine is 5.2.17).

I am not satisfied with such hacky solution though. Is there some straightforward way or something I could do simpler?

Comment: Why don't you use a native SQL update?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli probably because I was too focused to make solution in "Force update..." question working :-). Native SQL is actually nice idea. Just thinking how complex would be to synthetize `update my_entity set id = id where id = 1` command from Hibernate metadata, especially for entities with composite key etc.